# Connect to remotely MySQL with PHP and Eclipse

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE for PHP to develop my webapps.
Since I'm kind of a newbie, the way I'm doing it right now:
1. Writing the code in Eclipse, setting the MySQL host to 'localhost'
2.  Moving the files to my php server
3.  Refreshing the php page and seeing the result on the page and in the DB

I also installed a WAMP server with an Xdebug debugger but I think that it's quite a hassle to develop on the PC and then moving it all to the server.

My question:
Is there any way better to develop for PHP?
Is there a way to connect remotely to the PHP files on the server, connect remotely to the MySQL DB on the server?
Would I be able to debug that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm storing the test version of database in my developer machine.
So, I have the properly worked version in production(database and php scripts) and developer version.

UPD: web server for running php scripts - in developer machine too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, you can eliminate step 2 entirely by setting up a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) on your machine. You can put your scripts in the folder specified in the virtual host directive. Then whenever you need to see the changes you've made to your scripts you just have to hit refresh.